# Conditional for_each with dynamic resource in Terraform

Tags: postgresql, terraform

I need to update the "database_flags" property to DB Instances in GCP. As of now, only Postgres DB Instances support the "database_flags" property, and it is not applicable to MySQL Instances. I am using a dynamic block to check, if the DB instance is Postgres, then "database_flags" should be applied, but if the DB instance is MySQL, then database_flag should not be used.

My requirement is to apply "database_flags" only to the Postgres instance and not to MySQL instance.

I have used the below dynamic block:

```
dynamic "database_flags" {
  for_each = "substr(${var.database_version}, 0, 5)" == "MYSQL" ? [] : [1]
  content {
    name  = "log_lock_waits"
    value = "On"
  }
```

But I get this error message:

```
Error: Error, failed to update instance settings for : googleapi: Error 404: The requested flag is either misspelled or unsupported by Cloud SQL., invalidFlagName
```

However, the "database_flags" property is also getting applied to MySQL DB Instances.

Is there any way I could use conditions within the content of the dynamic block in Terraform to prevent "database_flags" from getting applied to MySQL DB Instances?

Full Code:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "master" {
  name             = "${var.name}"
  database_version = "${var.database_version}"
  region           = "${var.region}"

  settings {
    tier = "${var.tier}"
    disk_type   = "${var.disk_type}"
    disk_size   = "${var.disk_size}"
    disk_autoresize   = "${var.disk_autoresize}"
    availability_type = "${var.availability_type}"
  
  ip_configuration{
      ipv4_enabled  =   "true"
    }

  maintenance_window {
    day = "${var.day}"
  }

  dynamic "database_flags" {
    for_each = "substr(${var.database_version}, 0, 5)" == "MYSQL" ? [] : [1]
    content {
     name  = "log_lock_waits"
     value = "${var.log_lock_waits}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of database_version variable?

Comment: The `log_lock_waits` is expecting a boolean value instead of a string